# Can't solve this ODE using Laplace transforms!

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Can't seem to solve this. I get an expression as follows

$d^2x/dt^2 + x = 2t$

$X(s) = (2+5s^3)/s^2(s^2+1)$

But solving this using partial fractions doesn't get me the right answer. I would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find $X(s)(s^2+1)+I(s)=\frac{2}{s^2}$ where $I$ is the terms coming from the initial conditions. I guess in your case $I(s)=-5s$, meaning $x(0)=5,x'(0)=0$. Now you have partial fractions to do. What goes awry when you try to do the partial fractions?

Comment: I got got the same expression when subsituting the intial conditions, my problem must be with the partial fractions - i'll have another go

Comment: I'll take off my downvote if you: 1) Type the equation correctly, 2) include the initial conditions, 3) write down your attempt to solve the problem. This is too low effort

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if my decades of experience teaching DE can guess your mistake using almost no context:

When $s^2$ appears in the denominator, a lot of students make the mistake of treating it as an irreducible quadratic.  They put

$$\frac{As+B}{s^2}$$

in the Ansatz.   But this is wrong.  It's really the linear factor $s$ to the 2nd power.  So they should have written

$$\frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s^2}.$$

How good was my guess?

Comment: Wrong, I did do this - but good try!

Comment: @zcecmsah  This was a hint.  I'm hinting that you 1. should use MathJax and 2. give some context.  You didn't even give us the initial conditions.  How can you expect help when you won't exert even the tiniest effort?  We can't work in a vacuum.  Why didn't you follow the simple instructions in the orientation?  You have the badge, so you must have read it.